# Logging out of react app results in nullpointer in homescreen

Tags: react-native, react-context

I'm working on a react application with a login page. When the user logs in successfully, the backend returns a user-object (JSON), containing some user properties (id, username, ...) aswel as JWT token. The user-object gets stored in AsyncStorage (so the user only has to log in once).

```
try {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(data));
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e.message);
}

dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', authUser:data});
```

The state :

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(

        (prevState, action) => {
          switch (action.type) {
            case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                authUser: action.authUser,
                isLoading: false,
              };
            case 'SIGN_IN':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isSignout: false,
                authUser: action.authUser,
              };
            case 'SIGN_OUT':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isSignout: true,
                authUser: null,
              };
          }
        },
        {
          isLoading: true,
          isSignout: false,
          authUser: "",
        }
    );
```

The second time i retrieve the user-object from the AsyncStorage and pass it to the state.

```
try {
   authUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authUser');
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e.message);
}
dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', authUser: JSON.parse(authUser) });
```

I use a UserContext to pass the `authUser` to my welcome screen :

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
   <UserContext.Provider value={{authUser: state.authUser }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
         <RootStack.Navigator mode="modal" headerMode="none">
            {state.isLoading ? (
               <RootStack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
            ) : state.authUser == null ? (
               <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={AuthenticationStackScreen} />
            ) : (
               <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            )}
         </RootStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
   </UserContext.Provider>
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

In my homescreen I print a welcome message containing the username and a `signOut` button :

```
function HomeScreen(props) {

    const { signOut } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    const { authUser } = React.useContext(UserContext);

    return (

        <View style={{ flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:'cyan' }}>

        <Text>Hallo {authUser.username}</Text>
            <Button title="Log out" onPress={signOut} />
            <Text>HomeScreen </Text>
        </View>

    );
}
```

When a user logs in or was already logged in, the Homescreen is shown correctly with the correct username. The problem appears when the logout button is clicked. The signOut method in the authContext gets called, which logs out the user and removes the object from the AsyncStorage :

```
signOut: async () => {

   try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('authUser');
   } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
   }
   dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' })
}
```

**The problem :**
The state changes to `SIGN_OUT` which brings me back to the login page. But since i've cleared the user-object, the welcome notification throws an error because `{authUser.username}` is `null`:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'authUser.username')
```

I didn't expect the WelcomeScreen to be re-rendered when clicking the sign-out button. Did i mess up the structure of my application, or why is this? Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could handle it by accessing the username only if authUser is available {authUser?.username}, it maybe re rendering as you are having two different context providers

Comment: Hi Guruparan, is there a way i can pass the user-object in the authContext aswell? So i can only use one context?

Comment: The context can hold any object so i'm sure that you can put all these info into a single object and place it in the context so its possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) useContext will always re-render when the context value changes, so that's why HomeScreen is been called again.

Another thing you need to fix is the authUser initial state to be equal to authUser signOut state:

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(

        (prevState, action) => {
          switch (action.type) {
            case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                authUser: action.authUser,
                isLoading: false,
              };
            case 'SIGN_IN':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isSignout: false,
                authUser: action.authUser,
              };
            case 'SIGN_OUT':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isSignout: true,
                authUser: null,
              };
          }
        },
        {
          isLoading: true,
          isSignout: false,
          authUser: "", //MAKE THIS THE SAME AS SIGN_OUT (null)
        }
    );
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I've changed the default value of the authUser to null, thanks for the advice! I'm am being redirected to the Login, and not to the HomeScreen, so that looks ok. I've checked the authUser and it's definitely null, so i really don't have a clue why the HomeScreen would re-render and give this error. Could it have something to do with me using two Contexts? I've tried adding the user-object to the authContext as well, but i didn't get this to work. Is this even possible? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TimCreemers I edited the answer to mention that useContext triggers a rerender.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the support. As far as i can tell i'm not doing a useContext in my signOut functionality? My apologies if i'm asking stupid questions, the contexts are kinda hard to understand for me

Comment: @TimCreemers You are using useContext inside HomeScreen. So this screen will rerender any time the context value changes.